# Inner and outer expansions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory, boundary-layer

I'd really appreciate some help with the following question.

> Find inner and outer expansions, correct up to and including terms of O(ε), for the function

> $$ f(x;ε) = \frac{e^{-\frac{x}{ε}}}{x} + \frac{\sin x}{x} - \coth x $$

By setting $x=O(1)$, the first term becomes exponentially small, and so (I think) the outer expansion is simply

$$ f(x;ε) = \frac{\sin x}{x} - \coth x $$

To find the inner expansion, I take $x=O(ε)$. I therefore rescale $x$ using $x=εX$, with $X=O(1)$, and set $f(x;ε)=F(X;ε)$.

Plugging this into the original equation, I obtain

$$ F(X;ε) = \frac{e^{-X}}{εX} + \frac{\sin(εX)}{εX} - \coth(εX) $$

I'm not sure if this is right and, if so, how to continue? At some point, I may need to use matching?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Edit (following Lutz's comment):

Using Taylor expansions, we can write

$$ \frac{\sin(εX)}{εX} ≈ 1 - \frac{1}{6}ε^2X^2 $$
$$ \coth(εX) ≈ \frac{1}{εX} + \frac{εX}{3} $$
$$ \frac{e^{-X}}{εX} ≈ \frac{1}{εX} - \frac{1}{ε} + \frac{X}{2ε} - \frac{X^2}{6ε} $$

Then plugging into our original equation, the $\frac{1}{εX}$ terms cancel, and we are left with:

$$ F(X;ε) = 1 - \frac{1}{6}ε^2X^2 - \frac{εX}{3} - \frac{1}{ε} + \frac{X}{2ε} - \frac{X^2}{6ε} + ... $$

I assume this isn't the final answer, but I'm unsure of how to rewrite the last terms, which have $ε$ in their denominators?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now insert that for $x\approx 0$ you have
$$\frac{\sin x}{x}\approx 1-\frac16x^2$$
and
$$
\coth(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{e^x-e^{-x}}\approx\frac{1+\frac12x^2}{x+\frac16x^3}\approx \frac1x+\frac13x
$$
to cancel out the singularities at $x=0$.

Comment: Hi @LutzLehmann , thanks for the help! I've made some more progress and edited it into the question so you can see, but I'm still a little stuck if you're able to help?

Comment: You will need to keep $\frac{1-e^{-X}}{X}$ together as a function continuous on $[0,\infty)$ and with exponential decay. In the end you get a component of size $ε^{-1}$, this is part of the inner solution.